# List All Docs with @ibm-cloud/cloudant

Tags: node.js, database, migration, database-migration, cloudant

So recently IBM deprecated @cloudant/cloudant and have moved on to @ibm-cloud/cloudant. I was in the process of doing a todo app to learn Cloudant along with some other things and so had to migrate to the new package.

[image]

As you can see from my Cloudant dashboard, I have a database with name "todo-vue-hapi" and there are 3 docs in the db. According to the [migration docs](https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) to list all the documents before you would use `db.list` now you should use `service.postDesignDocs` so I connected everything and used the following code:

```
const response = await db.postDesignDocs({
  db: 'todo-vue-hapi',
})
```

This gives back a response object with the following result property:

```
{result: { total_rows: 0, offset: 0, rows: []}
```

The 3 docs are not there! I'm wondering how I can query everything in the database "todo-vue-hapi". Help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `postDesignDocs` function only returns [design documents](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-design-documents), which are special Cloudant documents containing index definitions.

To return all documents in a database you need to use the `_all_docs` API endpoint which is implemented as the [postAllDocs](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/cloudant?code=node#postalldocs) function:

```
const response = await db.postAllDocs({
  db: 'todo-vue-hapi',
  includeDocs: true,
  limit: 10
})
```

This should return you all documents in the database, including regular and design documents.